# Unable to reconfigure locale in raspberry pi

Tags: boot, locale

When I boot pi it it throws the following warnings:

> -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
>   -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
>   ->bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)

When I do

```
>locale
 locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I changed the contents of /etc/default/locale to the following

```
# File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I tried to reconfigure locale using

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

But every time the menu opens, with no selection made. I have to select

> en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8

every time.And selecting this throws the error

> Generating locales (this might take a while)...
>   Generation complete.
>   *** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANG=en_GB.UTF-8   LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

How do I remove these warnings?

Comment: Have you used `raspi-config` to setup International options?

Comment: yes I did that but to no avail. I had wheezy when this problem was there. Now I have installed Jessie, still this persists. I don't know how after formatting the card and installing a new os this problem can still be there.

Comment: This worked for me... http://daker.me/2014/10/how-to-fix-perl-warning-setting-locale-failed-in-raspbian.html Good luck!!!

Answer (score 34):

This blog post helped me:
Raspberry Pi -- Fixing your Locale
http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/raspberry-pi-setting-your-locale

- Edit `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment the line with `en_US.UTF-8` 
  e.g. `sudo nano /etc/locale.gen`
  uncomment line by deleting leading `#`
- Run `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`
- Run `sudo update-locale en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: This worked for me also

Comment: Thank you, This works still as of November 2019.

Answer (score 14):

The other answers weren't working for me but I found one that did.

Run `sudo nano /etc/default/locale`

Change it to include these three lines:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then reboot the system and it should be updated.

Comment: This is what worked for me after creating images using rpi-imager.  The original Noobs created image was ok.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/locale.gen` then uncomment the following line:

```
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Run:

```
sudo locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
sudo update-locale en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Verify it;

```
locale
```

You may get:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
```

And Done !!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you flashed a new image and it continues to not work, it sounds like you might have a hardware issue.  Do you have another raspberry pi to try it on?  If you do and you get the same error, make sure you are downloading the right [image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) or try [noobs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/) to make sure.  If you do not have another raspberry pi, I recommend running `sudo update-locale en_US.UTF-8` and seeing if that fixes the issue.